# Batch file to check if multiple services with a common word in their name are running and start them, if it is not running?

Tags: web-services, wcf, batch-file, service

I want to perform the following actions via batch file:

Action--> Check if multiple services with their names having common word in them are running or not, such as following criteria's:

```
      1) IF services name contain word "Demo Service"
      2) IF services name contain word "Demo Mobile Service"
      3) IF services name contain word "Demo StTime Service"
```

Action--> If all of the services are running, quit the batch!

Action--> If one or more services are not running, start the services one by one

I have a server with about 50 services on them, sample name of the services:

001122 Demo Service

001122 Demo Mobile Service

001252 Demo Service

001252 Demo Mobile Service

001252 Demo StTime Service

For some reasons (Resources being one of them) few of the services stop at any random time, So i need this script working until i get more resources.

I found bits and pieces and tried to compile them something as below.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "SERVICE_NAME=Demo Service"
echo %SERVICE_NAME%
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,100) DO (
set "SERVICE_NAME=%SERVICE_NAME%%%G"
echo Starting "!SERVICE_NAME!"
net start "!SERVICE_NAME!"
)

set "M_SERVICE_NAME=Demo Mobile Service"
echo %M_SERVICE_NAME%
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,100) DO (
set "M_SERVICE_NAME=%M_SERVICE_NAME%%%G"
echo Starting "!M_SERVICE_NAME!"
net start "!M_SERVICE_NAME!"
)

set "ST_SERVICE_NAME=Demo StTime Service"
echo %ST_SERVICE_NAME%
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,100) DO (
set "ST_SERVICE_NAME=%ST_SERVICE_NAME%%%G"
echo Starting "!ST_SERVICE_NAME!"
net start "!ST_SERVICE_NAME!"
)
```

1st problem, it tries to look for 100 services because of the FOR loop, 2nd it says invalid service name so I am not sure how to fix the lixe criteria.
Can certain someone please help me with this batch file ?

Comment: At first, you should comment out `@echo off` -- many problems can be easily solved then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see. First, list all services with `sc query state= all` which will give a long list of such items:

```
SERVICE_NAME: w32time  
DISPLAY_NAME: Windows Time  
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING  
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)  
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)  
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)  
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0  
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0  
        PID                : 1064  
        FLAGS              :
```

Now filter the list by `DISPLAY_NAME:`, `Demo` and `Service`:

```
sc query state= all | findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME: .*Demo .*Service"
```

The output will be:

> DISPLAY_NAME: 001122 Demo Service
>       DISPLAY_NAME: 001122 Demo Mobile Service
>       DISPLAY_NAME: 001252 Demo Service
>       DISPLAY_NAME: 001252 Demo Mobile Service
>       DISPLAY_NAME: 001252 Demo StTime Service

Now get the text after the first word and start the service.
The final code is:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('
    sc query state^= all ^| findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME: .*Demo .*Service"
') do net start "%%b"
```

To hide the messages use `net start "%%b" 2>nul`.

Comment: I tried to query using sc query state= all | findstr /r /c:"DISPLAY_NAME: .*Demo .*Service"  --- It worked fine, listed all the services.

However, when i created a batch file with the code you provided it does not do anything, i added pause in the end of it and it shows no error or anything. Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in response to the accepted answer given by wOxxOm:

You should execute `net` with the `SERVICE_NAME` instead of the `DISPLAY_NAME`.  This is because a Service's display name can differ from the actual service name itself, and the `net` command utilizes the service name.

You can see this, for instance, in the original example given, where the `DISPLAY_NAME` is **Windows Time**, but the `SERVICE_NAME` is **w32time**.

Since you want to search by `DISPLAY_NAME` specifically in this case, there needs to be a way where the original answer incorporates the `SERVICE_NAME` of the matched `DISPLAY_NAME` service into the `net` command.